# How can I open a new terminal window from a terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console, terminal

How can I open a new terminal window from a terminal in linux?

Comment: Related: [How to launch an application with default “terminal emulator” on Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32547/80216) and [Why does “man x-terminal-emulator” return the output of “man gnome-terminal”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/500972/325633)

Comment: Why don't you simply do a `xterm &`?  Please also specify what GUI (Desktop) you are using.

Answer (score 31):

That's system specific. On KDE, just type `konsole`. On Gnome, it's `gnome-terminal`. What should work on every X system is `xterm`.

Edit: Removed the bit about `$TERM`, as it is an ["identifier for the text window’s capabilities"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html) and not necessarily the name of an executable binary.

Comment: In Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon I have TERM="xterm-256color" that does not correspond to a binary command to open a terminal :(

Comment: Edited my answer, the thing I wrote about `$TERM` was based on a wrong assumption. I guess `gnome-terminal` should work on Mint.

Comment: `gnome-terminal -- commandhere` https://askubuntu.com/q/974756/462615

Answer (score 22):

I think what you want is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> -> new tab

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> -> new terminal

Comment: +1 because it's a keyboard shortcut...which doesn't address the question asked (as I understand it), but sure helps me! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The command that I set to run on startup is "x-terminal-emulator" and that opens the terminal we all know and love.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using an external program such as `pcmanfm` to launch a new terminal. This way, your root permissions and login state remain in the new terminal.

1. If you don't have it already, include the first line, otherwise skip this step (or don't, it won't reinstall):

   ```
   # apt-get install pcmanfm
   ```
2. Start the filemanager pcmanfm

   ```
   # pcmanfm
   ```

   a file manager window will now open, showing your current working directory.
3. Select this window and press <kbd>F4</kbd>. A new `terminal` window will now open with your current permissions (eg root).
4. `pcmanfm`, the file manager, can now be closed.

Comment: Thx bertieb, it looks a lot better like this.

Comment: No problem, you may want to have a glance at [the formatting help page](/help/formatting) - it's a bit different to what you might be used to but you should get up to speed pretty quick :)

Comment: @bertieb: You can still apply numbered formatting by using a period after each number instead.

Comment: @Jamal I was avoiding `<ol>` because (ironically) I couldn't remember how to make it respect multi-line content like code blocks!

Answer (score 2):

Press `ALT + F2`, then type-in `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` and Enter.

Answer (score 2):

I am using xfce4 as my desktop environment (DE) on Arch Linux,
so for me it was `xfce4-terminal`.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> should mostly works. 
But you might have a different desktop environment (DE). 
The command depends on your DE, not on your Linux distro.

For Kde    -> `konsole`
For GNOME  -> `gnome-terminal`
For xfce4  -> `xfce4-terminal`
For Cinnamon -> `x-terminal-emulator`
For MATE   -> `mate-terminal --window`
For Unity  -> `gnome-terminal --profile=Default`
For Pantheon -> `pantheon-terminal -w ''` 
[for Pantheon DE look at this also](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/open-a-new-tab-in-terminal-instead-of-a-new-window)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: If there really are such things as `genome-terminal` and “pathenom”,  please provide references.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have command line access (via ssh, for example), you should research [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen).

Answer (score 0):

I always do things like this with the disown command.

For example:

```
lxterminal &disown
```

And voila, we have a new lxterminal process that is not preoccupying your former terminal with debugging output. This can be used for most programs, not just terminals so I ended up using it a lot, especially good to know for scripting.

Comment: or this: `xterm &`

Comment: @Qwerty or that, but doesn't this xterm window close if you close the window that issued the command? If you disown it it will keep running.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can do it using xdotool.

To do so, you have to install xdotool with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

and then you can use the command below to open up a new terminal window:

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+t
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional solution for those running a Linux flavor (Ubuntu etc.) via the Windows Subsystem for Linux:

Shift-click the Linux application icon in your taskbar.

This will open a second terminal window.